# iOS 7 presentViewController shows black screen and SIGABRT

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I use two buttons on right UIBARBUTTON by writing code in the method[ViewDidLoad].

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcOEW.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG3eT.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0xsB.png

I want to use +plus button to move to AddNameViewController  but it results in a `Fail[sigabrt]`.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBq2m.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdw8T.png

I think the error is in the following code.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
AddNameViewController *sfvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddNameViewController.m"];
[sfvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:sfvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: AddNameViewController *sfvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddNameViewController.m"];
Here replace "AddNameViewController.m" with you identifier name only. don't use extension.

Comment: sorry , [I did not check carefully before asked.]
Because  I tried many way to improve it.    although I change AddNameViewController.m to AddNameViewController.    it still show sigabrt. T^T

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
AddNameViewController *sfvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddNameViewController.m"]
```

For this:

```
AddNameViewController *sfvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddNameViewController"]
```

You need the name of the View Controller, not the file.

Answer (score 1):

Like Antonio said, you need the correct identifier for your view controller. The reason it crashes is because you get a nil view controller pointer back from the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` call and passing nil to `presentViewController:animated:completion:` causes your crash.

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
AddNameViewController *sfvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddNameViewController"];
[sfvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:sfvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and add identifier AddNameViewController in storyboard ID

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I did not check carefully before asking. Because I tried many ways to improve it. Although, I change `AddNameViewController.m` to `AddNameViewController` ,

It still show sigabrt.